# How to compute this improper integral below?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, integers

I believe that it converges.
And I am confused about why $$\int ^{\infty} _{-\infty}e^{-ikx}dk=0$$ if $x \neq 0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History

Comment: Did you mean $\int ^{\infty} _{-\infty}e^{ikx}dx$?

Comment: @neo I think he really meant what he wrote (since he specified "if $x\ne0$"). But this question is indeed equivalent to the duplicate you propose.

Comment: No, this integral as it is does not converge. The function $S(a,b)=\int_a^be^{-ikx}dk$ is for $k\ne 0$ non-constant periodic in $a,b$ and does thus not have a limit for $(a,b)\to(-\infty,\infty)$